# When does one use "zu Arbeiten" and when "zum Arbeiten"?

Tags: usage

DWDS has many examples of the use of both "zu Arbeiten" and "zum Arbeiten", and both always appear to translate to "to work". So why are there 2 different ways of saying the same thing?

Here are long lists from DWDS of, first, zu Arbeiten, capital A:

https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=@zu+@Arbeiten&corpus=zeit&date-start=1946&date-end=2018&format=full&sort=date_desc&limit=50

and, second, zum Arbeiten:

https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=@zum+@Arbeiten&corpus=zeit&date-start=1946&date-end=2018&format=full&sort=date_desc&limit=50

zu arbeiten, small "a" is not in question here.

Comment: Judging from the capital letters, I'd say that the former has the noun "die Arbeit" (and the latter the gerund of the verb "arbeiten"), but that doesn't really fit your translation. Can you cite some examples?

Comment: I'd believe the noun usually would rather be 'das Arbeiten' instead of the plural of 'die Arbeit'. But both may be correct, depending on context. Either case, context matters. So this single half phrases are hard to impossible to judge.

Comment: Please, provide the original links instead of bit.ly links. The latter are blocked by our firewall (certainly for good reasons).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That piece *zu Arbeiten* has *Arbeiten* as the dative plural of the noun *die Arbeit* as an argument to the preposition *zu*. That adverbial makes only sense in a very narrow range of contexts.

> Sein Werk steht in Beziehung **zu Arbeiten** seines Vaters.

*His oeuvre has relations **to works** of his father.*

While the piece *zum Arbeiten* has *Arbeiten* as the dative singular of the noun *das Arbeiten* made from the verb *arbeiten*. The meaning is similar to that of the English gerund, or sometimes, the infinitive.

> **Zum Arbeiten** geht er in die Werkstatt.

***For working** he goes to the workshop.*

Sometimes *zu Arbeiten* and *zum Arbeiten* become almost synonymous.

> Man zwingt ihn zum Arbeiten.

They force him to work.

> Man zwingt ihn zur Arbeit.

They force him to work on something.

> Man zwingt ihn zu Arbeiten.

They force him to work on multiple things.

Comment: Please see my follow-up question.

Answer (score 3):

*Zu arbeiten* (without capital A) means *to work* in the sense of, e.g.,

> I like to work.
>
> (Ich arbeite gerne. / Ich mag es, zu arbeiten.)

*Zum Arbeiten* means *to (the) work* in the sense of, e.g.,

> I came here to work.
>
> (Ich komme zum Arbeiten her.)

Here, *Arbeiten* is a noun.

Comment: Correct and good examples, but a bit more grammatical analysis would be helpful.

Comment: @phipsgabler "a bit more grammatical analysis would be helpful" –– Not to the average person. I can speak my mother tongue without understanding it's grammar. And research has shown that language learning through grammar does not work as well as language learning by example usage.

Answer (score 2):

In “zu Arbeiten”, “Arbeiten” is the plural of “die Arbeit” with an indefinite article.
In “zum Arbeiten” or “zu dem Arbeiten” we have the nominalisation “das Arbeiten” of The verb “arbeiten”.

Comment: So what is the difference in meaning?